# Npx undefined path in GIT SCM

Tags: node.js, git, reactjs, babeljs

I'm new to Git and NodeJS. I'm currently using ReactJS as well as Babel for my project. I want Babel to watch every time I modify a file and compile it to another folder. This is my folder structure:

```
Project Folder
  |__node_modules (contains node modules)
  |__public (complied scripts are placed here)
  |__src (uncomplied scripts)
    |__libs (JavaScript libs)
    |__app.js (Main JS file)   
  |__views (contains view files that need to be rendered)
  |__index.js (NodeJS config file)
  |__package.json
  |__package-lock.json
```

And this is my Git command:

```
$ npx babel --watch src --out-dir public . --presets react-app/prod
```

However I received this error:

```
Path must be a string. Received undefined
```

And Babel started compiling all JS files in the project. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance 
**Edit** I'm using npm version 5.6.0 and npx version 9.7.1

Comment: What are your `npm` and `npx` versions?

Comment: You need to include stack traces in errors, helping debug issues is exactly why they exist. This question is unanswerable without that.

Comment: @DavidR please check out my updated question

Comment: @loganfsmyth Hi there could you please show me an example? I'm new to npm so I don't get what you mean

Comment: @WebDegBrian Right below the `Path must be a string. Received undefined` text there'd normally be a bunch of lines with file paths and function names and things that explain where the error was created from.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Please check out my updated question

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite what I mean. It would look something like the error at the bottom of this issue: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4225 All the lines starting with "at" for example describe which of Babel's files were being processed at the time.

Comment: Also, I noticed that you have a `.` in your Babel command before the `--presets` argument, which is probably not what you want. You should remove that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I followed react tutorial: https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Comment: That tutorial has `--out-dir .` You've changed it to `--out-dir public`, which makes sense for your case, but you left the `.` in there on accident.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176891/discussion-between-webdeg-brian-and-loganfsmyth).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from npx not babel (confirmed by loganfsmyth). The command should be:

```
$ npx babel --watch src --out-dir public --presets react-app/prod
```

Answer (score 0):

try this once :$ npx babel --watch 'src/app.js' -o 'public/app.js' --presets react-app/prod   And let me know what you are getting now

Comment: It doesn't work. Still the same problem, babel couldn't find app.js

Comment: could you share the babel configuration file

Comment: It doesn't work, but thanks though, I found the answer